# How do I find out if I can push to a remote repository?

Tags: mercurial

In Mercurial, is there a way to find out if I'm authorized to push changes to a remote repository (without actually doing a hg push)? I simply want to verify that the settings in hgrc on the local and remote server is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to be *really* sure is to try it—and even then, if it succeeds, that just means you *had* permission; maybe you don't now.

That said, you can simply push to them a commit that you got *from* them, to see if you have all the permissions required to get that far.  You will end up sending them nothing and writing nothing, but you'll test as much of that code path as you can test without actually sending them something.

Comment: Would an `incoming` or `outgoing` work just as well as a real push?

Comment: No, because those two merely check the *read* direction; you want to get Mercurial to go as far as you can get it to go down the "write a commit to the other side" path. Incoming is purely read-only and `outgoing` is (probably—I haven't actually checked) implemented using the read path as well, because it can be and that's lighter-weight.